# Child Sprite appearing under the parent

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

I am simply trying to add a sprite "light" on top of "spaceship". So as you can see below that I added light as the child of the spaceship, however, the light is appearing below the spaceship, as seen in the picture below. Can anyone tell me why this is happening, and how can I fix it?

```
- (void)newSpaceshipAtLocation:(CGPoint)location{
SKSpriteNode *hull = [[SKSpriteNode alloc]initWithImageNamed:@"Spaceship"];

hull.position = location;
hull.name = @"Spaceship";
hull.scale = 0.5;

SKSpriteNode *light = [self lights];
light.position = CGPointMake(hull.size.width / 5.0, hull.size.height/5.0);
[hull addChild:light];

[self addChild:hull];
}

- (SKSpriteNode *)lights{
SKSpriteNode *light = [[SKSpriteNode alloc]initWithColor:[NSColor yellowColor] size:CGSizeMake(50.0, 50.0)];

SKAction *blink = [SKAction sequence:@[
                                       [SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:0.5],
                                       [SKAction fadeInWithDuration:0.5],
                                       ]];
[light runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:blink]];
light.name = @"light";

return light;
}
```

[image: Yellow light under the spaceship]

Comment: You forgot the picture.

Comment: @reecon I can't directly upload the picture here, because I don't have enough reputation. It's in the link below.

Comment: Yeap, got it. I missed the link to the picture. Sorry.

Comment: Try calling `[hull addChild:light];` after `[self addChild:hull];`

Comment: @akashg Already did that, doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `zPosition` property on `light`. If you set it to anything higher than the `hull` sprite, it should work.

Comment: Thanks, that does seem to solve the issue. Although, I still want to understand why it wasn't working before. If you could explain that, it would be wonderful.

Comment: Hmmm...not quite sure. Although there's something funny with the way you're setting the position. The scale of `hull` does not actually affect the frame of the sprite. If you're creating a whole bunch of ship objects, maybe the `light` that's showing up below the `hull` is actually a `light` from another `hull`. Does that make sense?